# How to send emails in eWay recurring payment?

Tags: payment-gateway

I am using eWay payment gateway. I have done recurring payment using eway php rebill source from their site & is working fine. But how would i send emails(custom) to the user? Also i would want to maintain these transactions in database. Is there something like Paypal's IPN in eWay?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to send a custom email to the user you'll need to do that separate from the recurring billing process. Unfortunately there isn't a notification of payment events, the closest you could get would be to do a regular `QueryTransactions` to get recent transactions.

Alternatively if you would like more flexibility and control, you could store your user's card details as [Tokens in eWAY](https://eway.io/api-v3/#token-payments), then manage the scheduling in your application.